# Create a Picasa album and upload images to it with PHP and cURL

Tags: php, picasa

All of the tutorials I've found for creating Picasa albums and uploading pictures use the Zend Framework which I haven't studied.

Is it possible to upload images and create albums using PHP and cURL?

My images are stored in the directory `e:/images` and the image information is stored in a MySQL table like this:

```
SET SQL_MODE="NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `picasaimage` (
  `id` bigint(1) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `content` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `tags` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `license` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `image_path` varchar(150) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `width` int(4) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `height` int(4) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=0 ;
```

I'm getting the Google Client authentication code using the following code:

```
<?php  
$ch = curl_init();  

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.google.com/accounts/ClientLogin");  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);  

$data = array('accountType' => 'GOOGLE',  
'Email' => 'youremailaddress@gmail.com',  
'Passwd' => 'yourpassword',  
'source'=>'PHI-cUrl-Example',  
'service'=>'lh2');  

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);  

$hasil = curl_exec($ch);  

echo $hasil;  
//SID=DQA...oUE  
//LSID=DQA...bbo  
//Auth=DQA...Sxq  
?>
```

Can anyone give some guidance on creating an album named `test` and uploading the images to it?

**EDIT1:**

How to add photo license when I upload photos with php scripts?

reference on http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Commons:Picasa_Web_Albums_files

```
Creative Commons Attribution 3.0 Unported (CC-BY)
Creative Commons Attribution-Share Alike 3.0 Unported
Unlicensed
Creative Commons Attribution-Noncommercial 3.0 Unported
Creative Commons Attribution-No Derivative Works 3.0 Unported
Creative Commons Attribution-Noncommercial-No Derivative Works 3.0 Unported
```

Check the response data from api get album photo, there should be have something like:

```
       "gphoto$license":{
           "$t":"ATTRIBUTION_NON_COMMERCIAL_NO_DERIVATIVES",
           "id":3,
           "name":"Attribution-Noncommercial-No Derivative",
           "url":"http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-nd/3.0"
        },
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's some code for creating the album. We'll pick up with the cURL call to authenticate.

```
//This is the cURL call to authenticate. We'll splitting out the return values 
//to more easily get the auth code.
$ret = explode("\n",curl_exec($ch));  

//Save all of the return values to an array so we can get them more easily later
$gvals = array();
foreach($ret as $item) {
    $flds = explode("=", $item);

    if(count($flds) > 1) {
        $gvals[$flds[0]] = $flds[1]; 
    }
}

//This is the authentication header we'll need to pass with each successive call
$authHeader = 'Authorization:  GoogleLogin auth="' . $gvals['Auth'] . '"';
$userId = "THE PICASA USER ID GOES HERE";
$feedUrl = "https://picasaweb.google.com/data/feed/api/user/$userId";

//This is the XML for creating a new album.
$rawXml = "<entry xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom'
                xmlns:media='http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/'
                xmlns:gphoto='http://schemas.google.com/photos/2007'>
              <title type='text'>Test album from PHP</title>
              <summary type='text'>This is a test album</summary>
              <gphoto:location>Louisville</gphoto:location>
              <gphoto:access>public</gphoto:access>
              <gphoto:timestamp>1152255600000</gphoto:timestamp>
              <category scheme='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#kind'
                term='http://schemas.google.com/photos/2007#album'></category>
            </entry>";

//Setup our cURL options
//Notice the last one where we pass in the authentication header
$options = array(
            CURLOPT_URL=> $feedUrl,
            CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER=> false,
            CURLOPT_POST=> true,
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER=> true,
            CURLOPT_HEADER=> true,
            CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION=> true,
            CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS=> $rawXml,
            CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER=> array('GData-Version:  2', $authHeader, 'Content-Type:  application/atom+xml')
        );
curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);

//This call will create the Picasa album.
//The return value is XML with a bunch of information about the newly created album.
$ret = curl_exec($ch);
```

---

**Uploading a photo** works in a similar fashion:

http://code.google.com/apis/picasaweb/docs/2.0/developers_guide_protocol.html#PostPhotos

Here's functioning code for uploading an image *without* metadata:

```
$userId = "USER ID GOES HERE";
$albumId = "ALBUM ID GOES HERE";
$albumUrl = "https://picasaweb.google.com/data/feed/api/user/$userId/albumid/$albumId";
$imgName = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/picasa/cute_baby_kitten.jpg';

//Get the binary image data
$fileSize = filesize($imgName);
$fh = fopen($imgName, 'rb');
$imgData = fread($fh, $fileSize);
fclose($fh);

$header = array('GData-Version:  2', $authHeader, 'Content-Type: image/jpeg', 'Content-Length: ' . $fileSize, 'Slug: cute_baby_kitten.jpg');
$data = $imgData; //Make sure the image data is NOT Base64 encoded otherwise the upload will fail with a "Not an image" error

$ret = "";
$ch  = curl_init($albumUrl);
$options = array(
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER=> false,
        CURLOPT_POST=> true,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER=> true,
        CURLOPT_HEADER=> true,
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION=> true,
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS=> $data,
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER=> $header
    );
curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);
$ret = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

---

And here's an example of uploading a photo *with* metadata (finally!):

```
$albumUrl = "https://picasaweb.google.com/data/feed/api/user/$userId/albumid/$albumId";
$imgName = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/picasa/cute_baby_kitten.jpg';

$rawImgXml = '<entry xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
              <title>plz-to-love-realcat.jpg</title>
              <summary>Real cat wants attention too.</summary>
              <category scheme="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#kind"
                term="http://schemas.google.com/photos/2007#photo"/>
            </entry>';

$fileSize = filesize($imgName);
$fh = fopen($imgName, 'rb');
$imgData = fread($fh, $fileSize);
fclose($fh);

$dataLength = strlen($rawImgXml) + $fileSize;
$data = "";
$data .= "\nMedia multipart posting\n";
$data .= "--P4CpLdIHZpYqNn7\n";
$data .= "Content-Type: application/atom+xml\n\n";
$data .= $rawImgXml . "\n";
$data .= "--P4CpLdIHZpYqNn7\n";
$data .= "Content-Type: image/jpeg\n\n";
$data .= $imgData . "\n";
$data .= "--P4CpLdIHZpYqNn7--";

$header = array('GData-Version:  2', $authHeader, 'Content-Type: multipart/related; boundary=P4CpLdIHZpYqNn7;', 'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data), 'MIME-version: 1.0');

$ret = "";
$ch  = curl_init($albumUrl);
$options = array(
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER=> false,
        CURLOPT_POST=> true,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER=> true,
        CURLOPT_HEADER=> true,
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION=> true,
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS=> $data,
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER=> $header
    );
curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);
$ret = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: hey, these are some guide in official site, I have read, but still not know how to write it into php code. another question, how to add photo license when I upload? thanks.

Comment: I've updated with code for album creation. I'll post some photo upload code if I can figure that out.

Comment: OK, I've finally got some working code for an uploading an image. I'm still struggling with uploading an image with metadata though.

Comment: Final update to include an example of uploading a photo _with_ metadata. I ran into some issues that ultimately boiled down to calculating the Content-Length incorrectly. You can read all about that here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9841778/305

Comment: @mark-beik How to make it work with remote image url (http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/go-for-it-linux-app.jpg)? I tried with `$imgData = file_get_contents("$direct_img_url")` without metadata, but it didn't work. Why?

Comment: @KhurshidAlam Sorry, I really have no idea. You might come up with a test case demonstrating your problem and post it as a new question.

Comment: Ok. I will post a new question. But I think the problem is `file_get_contents("$direct_img_url")` and `fread($fh, $fileSize)` are not same. I don't know how I replicate `fread($fh, $fileSize)` without downloading the image. :(

Answer (score 1):

Expanding Mark's answer, you can send the XML directly from curl using **CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS**. However, instead of making an associative array, try passing the actual XML string like so:

```
$data= "<entry xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom'
    xmlns:media='http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/'
    xmlns:gphoto='http://schemas.google.com/photos/2007'>
  <title type='text'>Trip To Italy</title>
  <summary type='text'>This was the recent trip I took to Italy.</summary>
  <gphoto:location>Italy</gphoto:location>
  <gphoto:access>public</gphoto:access>
  <gphoto:timestamp>1152255600000</gphoto:timestamp>
  <media:group>
    <media:keywords>italy, vacation</media:keywords>
  </media:group>
  <category scheme='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#kind'
    term='http://schemas.google.com/photos/2007#album'></category>
</entry>";
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);  

$hasil = curl_exec($ch);
```